# Proof: All recursive functions are arithmetic (logic)

Tags: logic, computability

So I'm trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

**> All recursive functions are arithmetic**

The proof begins with:

"*It is sufficient to show that all arithmetic functions satisfy the properties in the definition of a recursive function*"

**Why is this true?** From my perspective this only proves that all arithmetic functions are recursive.

Comment: Your observation seems to be correct. Where do you have this from?

Comment: A lecture and a lecture note

Comment: One proves that the "basic" functions are arithmetical, and that the set of arithmetical functions is closed under the operations that get you new recursives from old. That is probably what is intended by the admittedly imprecise wording.

Comment: I think what it means is that the basis functions are arithmetic. Then by applying the recursion schemas we remain arithmetic. Basically recursive is the smallest class satisfying the definition.